# Como obter o número de processadores e núcleos pelo terminal?

Tags: linux, shell

Como verificar o número de processadores (CPUs) e núcleos pelo terminal do Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para imprimir o número de unidades de processamento, utilize o programa [`nproc`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/nproc.1.html).

Para mais detalhes, utilize o programa [`lscpu`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/lscpu.1.html), que mostra informações como arquitetura, número de CPUs, número de soquetes, threads por núcleo, núcleos por socket etc.

Comment: `nproc` mt bom, desconhcia

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra forma de obter essa informação é extraí-la do [`/proc/cpuinfo`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?proc%205).

```
~$ grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

uma outra forma de resolver esse problema é usando o comando:

cat /proc/cpuinfo| grep ^processor -c

Comment: pode também usar esse comando

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).